# How do I find a substring that always consists of an exact number of character types?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, string, substring

I have a column in a table where I would like to extract a substring so I could use it as a join to another table.

However I have an issue. The substring is not always on the same spot or preceded by the same character.

For example from the following:

```
SA 2019M05 7022b000003CDMmAAO - SA20190323 - 2019-03-23 09:20:00 Europe/Amsterdam
```

I only need:

```
7022b000003CDMmAAO
```

I have tried using a `SUBSTRING` in combination with a `CHARINDEX` and it is working. **However, I do not want to be dependent on the substring always starting with 70.**

Also, the code is not always in front of a `-`. The one part that is consistent is how the code is made. It always consists of numbers and letters in this particular order: `0000a000000aaaaaaa`.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN t.[jobName] LIKE '%70%' THEN SUBSTRING(t.[jobName],CHARINDEX('70',t.[jobName]),+18) ELSE NULL END AS [Code]
FROM table  t
```

So is there a way for me to find a substring that consists of `0000a000000aaaaaaa` type characters?

Comment: `patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]%', t.[jobName])`?

Comment: Is the code always after the second space? More than one sample, displaying different variations, would make things much easier; as we then don't need to guess.

Comment: Looks like a space delimited string, if so, you culd simply extract everything between second and third space.

Comment: No unfortunately not. From now on the code will start with the substring. But I still need to fix all the substrings from the past.

Comment: Will all the **old** one's be the 3rd (space) delimited item? Again, more samples will *really* help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Gserg patindex is working:

```
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z]%',t.[jobName]) = 0 THEN NULL 
      ELSE SUBSTRING(t.[jobName],PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z]%',t.[jobName]),+18) END AS [Code]
FROM table t
```

I just used the first 12 characters as I found out that the last part could vary. The case when is added so I only show the job names where the code is added. It doesn't look pretty but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach is to split your text data and make necessary checks. Using `PATINDEX()` and `SUBSTRING()` is a working solution, but one advantage here is the fact, that you may analyze every part of the splitted text. For SQL Server 2016+ you may use [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to split the values.

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   JobName varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   (JobName)
VALUES
   ('SA 2019M05 7022b000003CDMmAAO - SA20190323 - 2019-03-23 09:20:00 Europe/Amsterdam'),
   ('Randombla2019M04 7033v000000G2ZRBB0 - Randombla20190412 - 2019-04-17 09:40:00 Europe/Amsterdam'),
   ('AnotherRandom170419 7055v000000V3a9BB0 - NB-AnotherRandom - 2019-04-17 09:51:51 Europe/Amsterdam')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT s.[value] AS [Code]
FROM #Data d
OUTER APPLY 
   ( 
   SELECT [value]
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(d.JobName, ' ')
   WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]%', [value]) > 0
   ) s
```

Output:

```
------------------
Code
------------------
7022b000003CDMmAAO
NULL
NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a column in a table where I would like to extract a substring so I could use it as a join to another table.

For a `JOIN`, you don't have to extract the value.  You can use `LIKE` for this purpose:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM t JOIN
     anothertable t2
     ON t.jobName LIKE '% ' + t2.col + ' %'
```